# Can I go back to Singapore on a multiple entry visa that is still valid?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore

I am an Indian passport holder and have a Singapore multiple visa. I entered Singapore on 6 September 2014 and departed on 3 October 2014. I then traveled to Indonesia for one week. My Singapore multiple visa is valid up to 26 October 2014. My return ticket to India is from Singapore on 17 October.

Can I go back Singapore again on that visa?

Comment: Yes, you definitely can as long as your have multiple entry visa valid till the date of entry/exit in Singapore

Comment: Yes. But do make sure that your passport expires at least 6 months AFTER 17 October or you may be refused re-entry to Singapore. [My wife missed the 6 month limit by one day when we travelled SG-YOG-KL-SG and we got a new passport to ensure no problems re-rentering SG. ]

Answer (score 3):

A multiple entry visa by definition allows you to enter the country multiple times as long as the visa and any other additional conditions associated with the visa are valid.

So if the conditions regarding your travel to Singapore are the same as earlier and as you mentioned, your visa is still valid, you can travel to Singapore and then back to Indonesia.